# PHP 5.6.x source install with Apache, but openssl error occurs, dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: php, compilation, openssl, apache2, configure

I install PHP 5.6.39 with Apache.
My configure options is like below.

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/home1/apache/bin/apxs 
--with-config-file-path=/home1/apache/conf/ 
--prefix=/home1/php 
--enable-sysvsem 
--enable-sysvshm 
--enable-ftp 
--enable-pdo 
--with-zlib 
--with-mcrypt=/home1/apache 
--with-openssl=/home1/openssl
```

I use with-openssl option like this. **--with-openssl=/home1/openssl** 
Because OS openssl version is 1.0.1e, and i want use 1.1.0 like below

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./openssl //This openssl is located /home1/openssl/bin
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
```

Actually configure command is pass, but when i enter **make** i see this screen.

```
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c: In function ‘zif_openssl_x509_parse’:
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:1982: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:1983: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2011: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c: In function ‘php_openssl_generate_private_key’:
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3420: warning: ‘RSA_generate_key’ is deprecated (declared at /home1/openssl/include/openssl/rsa.h:193)
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3428: warning: ‘DSA_generate_parameters’ is deprecated (declared at /home1/openssl/include/openssl/dsa.h:122)
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3446: warning: ‘DH_generate_parameters’ is deprecated (declared at /home1/openssl/include/openssl/dh.h:135)
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c: In function ‘php_openssl_is_private_key’:
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3485: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3490: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3490: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3490: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3503: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3503: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3503: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3512: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3512: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3521: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c: In function ‘php_openssl_pkey_init_dsa’:
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3557: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3557: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3557: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3560: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3560: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3569: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3569: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c: In function ‘php_openssl_pkey_init_dh’:
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3580: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3580: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3583: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/home1/php-5.6.39/ext/openssl/openssl.c: In function ‘zif_openssl_pkey_new’:
```

I already search about this and find this post. But not help me.
https://github.com/fpoirotte/phpfarm/issues/23

If i am not use --with-openssl=/home1/openssl options then configure and make command is success. But i need this options. what i miss something?

Comment: Seems like PHP 5.6 cant support OpenSSL 1.1 @see https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/4133#issuecomment-321553488

Comment: btw. [PHP 5.6 hits EOL tomorrow](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: Embb.. Actually the production in my company is build php 5.6.8 with openssl 1.1.0. So i need a way to build php 5.6.x with openssl 1.1.0. In this case, is there any way to build with openssl 1.1.0?

Comment: I solve this problem with this. https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/566

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem with this link, patch for PHP 5.6.x with Openssl 1.1.0
https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/566